# Rails button_to remote gets messed up with onclick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails 3 app that is trying to perform some controller action with a button and :remote => true. At the moment, I don't want to even worry about the success of the action, I just want to have it happen on its own, and have some onclick script that hides the element immediately.

I can't seem to get them both to work at the same time. Here's the code that I'm using, which does the action just fine:

```
<%= button_to "Ignore", url_for(:controller => "requests", :action => "ignore", :id => request.id), :remote=>true %>
```

Now, when I try to add the onclick, that part gets executed, but suddenly the request is treated as HTML, so I get sent to a new page instead of treating it as "remote":

```
<%= button_to "Ignore", url_for(:controller => "requests", :action => "ignore", :id => request.id), :remote=>true, :onclick => "ignore('request_'"i.to_s"')" %>
```

As far as I can tell, the code for the button is created just fine, and the onclick works correctly, but adding that is making the request get messed up. Can anyone please help me out? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your onclick attribute has an error.

```
<%= button_to "Ignore", url_for(:controller => "requests", :action => "ignore", :id => request.id), :remote=>true, :onclick => "ignore('request_#{ i.to_s }'); return(false);" %>
```

However, you should consider doing this unobtrusively.

```
<%= button_to "Ignore", url_for(:controller => "requests", :action => "ignore", :id => request.id), :remote=>true, :'data-ignore-id' => i %>
```

then in the application.js

```
$('[data-ignore-id]').live('click', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var ignoreId = "request_" + $(this).attr('data-ignore-id').toString();
    ignore(ignoreId);
});
```

#### Update

The problem is that the button_to helper is building a form when you supply a url_for.  To the action that you are wanting to prevent is the onsubmit not the onclick.

```
<%= button_to "Ignore", url_for(:controller => "requests", :action => "ignore", :id => request.id), :remote=>true, :'data-ignore-id' => i %>
```

then in the application.js

```
$('[data-ignore-id]').submit(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var ignoreId = "request_" + $(this).attr('data-ignore-id').toString();
    ignore(ignoreId);
});
```

#### Update #2 - change because of where the data-ignore-id attr is.

```
<form method="post" action="/requests/41/ignore" data-remote="true" class="button_to">    
    <div>
        <input data-ignore-id="0" type="submit" value="Ignore" />
        <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="7S3K+ZFhSZij1ZAmSeggG0SpPozNwHBk4zxjegLIiKs=" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Change event to.

```
$('form > div input[data-ignore-id]').submit(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var ignoreId = "request_" + $(this).find('input[data-ignore-id]').attr('data-ignore-id').toString();
    ignore(ignoreId);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, I'm seeing the same behavior with both of those. The javascript gets executed ok, but the server is reporting that it's handling it as html:

    Started POST "/requests/33/ignore" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-06-23 16:16:22 -0700
      Processing by RequestsController#ignore as HTML

Comment: So the page isn't refreshing you are seeing a POST method on the server and you want something else?

Comment: No, POST is fine, and the controller action is triggered like I want. The problem is that for some reason, adding this onclick is changing the processing from JS to HTML. When that happens, Rails wants to format something and send me somewhere else, and I don't want to leave the current page.

Comment: I edited my answer to add a preventDefault call to the event.

Comment: Is the browser reloading? or are you getting a response that is the HTML version of the response?

Comment: The browser is reloading, which is not the case when I don't include the onclick.

Comment: Also, if I return false in the onclick, the controller action is never reached.

Comment: should be onSubmit instead of onClick

Comment: Getting closer :) So this is performing the 'ignore' action properly and processing as JS, but now the ignore() js function isn't being called

Comment: can you view source on the html page and cut and paste the form built here.  In particular, I would like to know which element has the data-ignore-id attribute.

Comment: <form method="post" action="/requests/41/ignore" data-remote="true" class="button_to"><div><input data-ignore-id="0" type="submit" value="Ignore" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="7S3K+ZFhSZij1ZAmSeggG0SpPozNwHBk4zxjegLIiKs=" /></div></form>

Comment: Thanks very much, I think we've got it doing what I want!

Answer (score 1):

this maybe helpful

```
=link_to "value", "javascript:function()", class: 'btn btn-default'
```